# Exception raised while calling custom .net ADF activity

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I have written Custom .Net Activity. Which is Connecting to Azure Storage & uploading data to the blob. While running ADF activity it throws exception that

```
Exception for file. Exception Message: Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount..ctor(Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth.StorageCredentials, System.String, System.String, Boolean)'.
```

The .Net code works fine in my local machine. Please help.

Comment: What version of Windows is running on the compute node of the batch service pool?

Comment: Windows Server 2012 & Batch OS Family as 3

Comment: Mmm, its a bit of a guess, but I wonder if there is some incompatibility with .Net versions and NuGet packages as this is working on your local machine. I'm assuming you zipped up the class library and all its references and put it in blob storage for ADF to pass to the batch service?

Comment: Yes. I zipped up package & put it in blob storage ADF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that Nuget is returning a version of Azure storage that is new for Custom activities and not yet recognized. The current version supported by Custom .Net Activity is 4.3 for Azure storage dll. Any version higher to 4.3 will raise exceptions.